# Should a very long function/series of functions be in one php file, or broken up into smaller ones?

Tags: php, api

At the moment I am writing a series of functions for fetching Dota 2 matches from the [Steam API.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) When someone fetches their games, I have to (for my use) take a history of all of their games (lets say 3 api calls), then all the details from each of those games (so if there's 200 games, another 200 api calls). This takes a long time, and so far I'm programming all of the above to be in one php file "FetchMatchHistory.php", which is run by the user clicking a button on the web page.

Another thing that is making me feel it should be in one file, is that I imagine it is probably good practice to put all of the information (In this case, match history, match details, id's etc.) into the database all at once, so that there doesn't have to be null values in the database?

My question is whether or not having a function that takes a very long time should be in just one PHP file (should meaning, is generally considered good practice), or whether I should break the seperate functions down into smaller files. This is very context dependent, I know, so please forgive me.

Is it common to have API calls spanning several PHP files if that is what you are making? Is there a security/reliability issue with having only one file doing all the leg-work (so to speak)?

Comment: You should learn basic PSR standards : http://php-fig.org

Comment: @Djay could you give me a small explanation of what that is?

Comment: Just click on the link I gave you

Comment: @Djay I did, thank you for the link. But perhaps for posterity, isn't it better to give a small description with a link? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good practice is to have a number of relevant functions grouped together in a php file that describes them, for organize them better and also for caching reasons for the parts that get updated more slowly than other. 
But speaking of performance, i doubt you'll get the performance improvements you seek by just moving code through files.

Personally i had the habit to put `everything` in a file, consistently:

- making my files fat
- hard-to-update
- hard-to-read
- hard to find the thing i want (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>** meltdown)
- wasting bandwidth uploading parts they did not need to be updated
- virtually disabling caching on server

I dont know if any of the above is of any use for your App, but breaking files into their relevant files/places did my life easier.

**UPDATE:**

About the database practice, you're going to query only the parts you want to be updated.
I dont understand why you split that logic in files, there's not going to give you performance. Instead, what is going to give you performance is to update only the relevant parts and having tables with relevant content. Speaking of multiple tables have a lot more sense, since you could use them as pointers to the large data contained in another tables, reducing the possible waste of data having just one table.

Also, dont forget a single table has limitations; I personally try to have as few columns as possible. Adding more and more and a day you can't add more because of the [row limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html). There is a maximum number of columns in general, but this limit rarely ever get maxed by developer; the increased per-row content itself is going to suck out that limit.

Comment: Yes, uploading the same big file again and again when i just updated a single line is wasted bandwidth, no? :)

Comment: I see thanks for the response. How about what I mentioned with a database? Is it considered bad practice to put (in one table) only parts of the data at a time. For example, if I have 5 columns, and I use one PHP file to put 3 cells of data in one row, then the remaining 2 from another file?

Comment: @vlzvl You mean in the developing stage, right? I mean, no bandwidth waste at runtime... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS, bandwidth waste on runtime is going to be wasted, regardless of the files you have :) I meant organizing the files in general.

Comment: @MarcoS, to clarify i see 2 kinds of wasted bandwidth: The one used for API calls and general for the Application and the one needed for the files going to uploaded/downloaded all the way till the end of developing and even after this, on updating the application from time to time. The first bandwidth is going to be wasted, regardless of how good the file organization is, and i didnt meant that bandwidth. I merely meant the files uploading/downloading files bandwidth in the bullets above.

Comment: @k4kuz0, im confused why you split the database work into files :) Check my update for databases in general

Comment: @vlzvl, I see. I usually relate "bandwidth" to data uploaded to the client, where it's important to optimize it's usage to give a better user experience...

Comment: @k4kuz0, I agree with vlzvl, you should probably RTFM a bit more... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS I try to RTFM as much as possible, but the 'manual' doesn't always give answers to every single question, and if it does, it's not always easy to find! Believe me, if I knew exactly where to find the answer, I wouldn't be bothering you nice people. :)

Comment: @Vlzvl Thanks, I wasn't actually doing what I mentioned with the database. But I thought it an option. I was just checking if it's considered bad practice. And from what I can gather, that is true, so I wont consider doing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whether to split server side code to multiple files or keep it in a single one is an organizational issue, more than a security/reliability one...

I don't think it's more secure to keep your code in separate source files.

It's entirely a  of how you prefer to organize and mantain your code base.

Usually, I separate it when I can find some kind of "categories" in my code.

Obviously, if you write OO code, the most common choice is to keep each class in a single file...

Comment: I see, organisation is quite subjective so I don't mind that. I was just worried that I was breaching some kind of "php rule of thumb" by having everything in one file. Especially since it seems it can take 5-10 minutes to finish executing (mostly due to the API having a one ping per second rule).

Comment: Execution time is very marginally affected by the number of files the source code is split to. Expecially when the code is cached...